# Is it possible for an apex classe to update code of another apex class at runtime?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, deployment, metadata-api, tooling-api

Currently, I am trying to update specific references in my apex code with something else, for example, changing all variables having name as LOG to Log, I know it can be done via vs code's replace all option. But the requirement is as such to make it happen via apex only.

Also, I have tried using a combination of Python and SFDX, which is possible from outside salesforce's context.

Could someone guide me on how we can make this happen via Apex itself (Probably via tooling API), or are there any restrictions set up by Salesforce which stop Apex class code updation from within Salesforce?

Update: Going with Metadata API with apex, also we'll expand this going forward with all metadatas of salesforce, if manipulating most metadatas won't be possible with Apex then I already have a solution working with Python+Tooling API for Apex class manipulation.

Comment: IMHO this is not a sensible requirement and sounds like one specified by a person who does not understand software development.

Comment: Is there any way this can be done @PhilW. I will try it out. I know it's a kind of redundant effort, but I have to do it anyhow.

If We cannot achieve it via apex, then I have Python+Sfdx OR Python+ToolingAPI approaches with me but they are the last resort.

Comment: If someone gave me this requirement I would push back and demand they explain why using standard developer tools isn't appropriate - things like VSCode search and replace or refactoring tools are what should be used for such code modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing stopping you from calling the tooling API or metadata API directly from Apex. However, code changes always require running all tests in production, so you would find that this solution could take several minutes or even hours to deploy such a small change.

For non-production orgs, it's as easy as using the tooling API via something like `/services/data/v57.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexClass/Name/MyClassName` with the PATCH verb to update the code. For production, you'll be limited to just the Metadata API and full deployments. It's possible, but would be painstakingly slow in most production orgs.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, I am trying with Metadata API, let's see how it goes, once done I will let everyone know here.